# Multimonitor on AMD Catalyst and 11.10 feels slowish

Tags: multiple-monitors, fglrx, radeon, ati

I have an AMD X6 desktop with plenty of RAM and a dual LG monitors driven by a Radeon HD 5830. The monitors are on DVI ports. AMD Catalyst Version 11.11. Tear free is on. Sync to V-black in ccsm, is disabled.

Multi monitor works OK, I have no problems dragging applications, working seemless between the two monitors, no instability issues whatsoever.

However, the whole experience with dual monitors is a bit sluggish. Window maximizing and minimizing feels slow, effects feel slower, the whole desktop experience feels other than on a single monitor.

Is this an Ubuntu issue or a GPU issue? Is there something to do to improve the overall experience? Will 12.04 improve on these issues? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **AMD Catalyst 12.1**+ version will fix your problems and improve performance in general. Download that one and test it out. It actually fixed several problems related to the 5800 series.